# How can i set the start value of a sequence to be the maxvalue of a column from a table in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I really don't know what details to offer, the question is basically in the title and i think it sums up everything.

```
|  -- table-- |
|_____________|
|  primary_id |
|------------ |
|bunch of data|
_______________
```

is it possible in oracle to create a sequence that will have the startvalue as table.primary_id maximum value? Or what are my alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible.

```
create sequence my_sequence_name start with <<insert id here>>;
```